# virt-manager error "format=dir: 'dir' invalid format" when creating qemu VM with ISO

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, virt-manager

This is virt-manager 1.0.1 on Fedora 20.  The server has libvirt 1.2.13-1, qemu 2.2.1-2 on Arch Linux.

Go to *File -> New Virtual Machine*.  Select *Use ISO Image* to install from then browse for it.
Finishing the wizard comes up with this rather ugly error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2015-04-28T07:24:09.432905Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Intel_Install/openSUSE/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on,format=dir: 'dir' invalid format
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 91, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1787, in do_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 403, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 467, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 2897, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2015-04-28T07:24:09.432905Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/Intel_Install/openSUSE/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,readonly=on,format=dir: 'dir' invalid format
```

I've tried to edit the VM in virt-manager (*Customize configuration before install*) to change format to *raw* but still see the same "format=dir: 'dir' invalid format" error.

How can I fix or bypass this error to build a VM? It was OK in previous versions.